# How to get a bool value from a path from firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to get a bool value from Firestore but I always get undefined when doing so.

I try to get the value using the following code:

```js
const flag = admin.firestore().collection("flags").doc("Air").sent;
```

I get `undefined` when I try to print the value of flag

[image]

This is the path to the value:

[image]

Can you help me discover my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `get()` on the `doc()` method.

```
const doc = await admin.firestore().collection("flags").doc("Air").get();
const flag = doc.data().sent; // doc.get('sent') should also work.
console.log(flag); // should print false
// I added "await" and "get()" method. Your function should be an "async"
// function.
```